# How to replace large count of string values from list found in the string

Tags: c#, regex, linq, list, replace

I'm wondering what is a fast and proper way if I got list about 2000 string values:

```
 List<string> strList = new List<string>();
```

For example:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 2000; i++)
{
    strList.Add("a" + i);
}
```

and I want replace each for input string if equal value is found:

```
string inputStr = "a1 a5 a80 a80 m124 a34 a300 e12 s00";
```

and if any word exist in strList of two thousand values, for example `if (strList.Any(inputStr.Contains))` then I want `inputStr.Replace` with `""` empty space then desired output should be::

```
"m124 e12 s00";
```

**EDIT:**

As my priority is to make this replacement fast as much it is possible, I've tried to compare `ElapsedMilliseconds` results of given solutions by Slai and sxmlln below. Both completely answered on my question and results is second:

*2000 values:*

```
string inputStr = "a1 a5 a80 a80 m124 a34 a300 e12 s00";
```

result:

```
ISet<String> : time: [ 0 ] fast
List<string> : time: [ 5 ] slow
HashSet<string> : time: [ 1 ] average
```

sometimes equal with same string and content:

```
ISet<String> : time: [ 0 ] fast
List<string> : time: [ 5 ] slow
HashSet<string> : time: [ 0 ] fast
```

*8000 values:*

```
string inputStr = "a1 a5 a80 a80 m124 a34 a4987 a300 e12 s00";
```

result:

```
ISet<String> : time: [ 2 ] fast
List<string> : time: [ 5 ] slow
HashSet<string> time: [ 3 ] average
```

*20000 values:*

```
string inputStr = "a1 a5 a80 a80 m124 a34 a4987 a17890 a300 e12 s00";
```

result:

```
ISet<String> : [ 7 ] fast
List<string> :  [ 12 ] average
HashSet<string> : [ 16 ] slow
```

*200000 values:*

```
string inputStr1 = "a1 a5 a80 a80 m124 a34 a4987 a17890 a300 e12 s00 a123676";
```

result:

```
ISet<String> : [ 105 ] fast
List<string> :  [ 111 ] average
HashSet<string> : [ 142 ] slow
```

`ISet<String>` is always less then `List<string>` and less or equal to `HashSet<string>`. And `List<string>` becomes faster then `HashSet<string>` after larger amount of values, but before this certain amount it is slower then `HashSet<string>` with `ElapsedMilliseconds` results.

Comment: Of course 2000 really isn't that much when dealing with the processing power of CPUs. BUT for such things with truly huge processes, it would be best to use StringBuilder as that just makes in-place changes to the string. Where in your scenario each change is creating a new string in a new slot of RAM memory.

Comment: interesting .. is the List method modified version of @Thili77's answer? Parsing the input string in a way that minimizes memory allocations should be generally fastest, but it's too much work and the parsing method has to be adjusted depending on the frequencies.

Comment: @Slai in most cases it is equal or near to HashSet<string> ElapsedMilliseconds results at least it is in the same places on fast/average/slow podium. but I can't say for sure, because I use this process without result string, just as it is given by Thili77 with add of condition strList.Any(inputStr.Contains) inside the if-statement, but when I'm trying to extract any value from strListNew it is empty. So to say something, I don't have any output with this solution, only implementation, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong with it

Answer (score 1):

There is no general fast and proper way as it depends on too many factors.

```
List<string> strList = Enumerable.Range(1, 2000).Select(i => "a" + i).ToList();
string inputStr = "a1 a5 a80 a80 m124 a34 a300 e12 s00";

string result = string.Join(" ", inputStr.Split(' ').Except(strList)); // "m124 e12 s00"
```

Most of the time is spent on creating a Set in the `.Except` LINQ extension, so the Set can be created only once in front for replacing more than one string :

```
var strSet = new HashSet<string>(Enumerable.Range(1, 2000).Select(i => "a" + i));

var result1 = string.Join(" ", inputStr1.Split(' ').Where(s => !strSet.Contains(s)));

var result2 = string.Join(" ", inputStr2.Split(' ').Where(s => !strSet.Contains(s)));
```

Comment: Hello, I've test results for solutions, check my edit

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a Set. They allow for fast lookups.

```
ISet<String> strSet = new HashSet<String>();  

for (int i = 1; i <= 2000; i++)
{
    strSet.Add("a" + i);
}
```

Next you can split your input into an array to do your check (since your input is able to be split by spaces).

```
string inputStr = "a1 a5 a80 a80 m124 a34 a300 e12 s00";
string[] inputs = inputStr.Split(' ');
```

Lastly, now you loop over your inputs and check to see if they exist in the `Set`. If they do not, then add them to your result.

```
// this is from System.Text namespace
StringBuilder sbResult = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var input in inputs)
{ 
    if (!strSet.Contains(input))
        {
            sbResult.AppendFormat("{0} ", input);
        }
    }
}

string result = sbResult.ToString().Trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using following code...

```
List<string> strListNew = new List<string>();
foeach(var item in strList){
  if ( /*your condition in here*/ )
  {
    strListNew.Add(""); 
  }
  else{
    strListNew.Add(item);
  } 
}
```

This will work for you...

Comment: Hello, I'm not sure, maybe I didn't understand it right, can you explain a bit more, how this code does what I ask

Comment: In this foreach loop you loop each string of strList one by one. So you have to check your condition on each , and then add into new list. In here new list is strListNew.

Comment: I got method name expected here (item(inputStr.Contains))

Comment: I didn't consider about condition more. Now I had edit that. So you will understand that now.

Comment: so just let me get, if I put there strList.Any(inputStr.Contains) how do I get final string, I just extract list content and it is empty. So I've edited my question, maybe it is not enough clear or am I doing something wrong with your code

Comment: check condition and then add into new stringListNew